# Using async keyword in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am playing with AWS Lambda using Node.js. After being tired of having to deal with callbacks I figured I could elegantly use `async/await` just like I am used to in C#.

```
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    db = await MongoClient.connect(process.env['MONGODB_URI']);
}
```

Even though this seemingly works when testing offline using `lambda-local`, it fails miserably when uploaded to AWS. It appears as if `async` keyword is not recognized. I am using the latest Node.js 6.10 runtime on AWS while my local version is 8.5. Is there a way around or should I abandon this approach and go back to using callbacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `async/await` feature was launched in Node.js v7.0 but was behind the `--harmony` flag as it was experimental. It was fully supported without the flag after Node.js v7.6.

Hence, you can't use `async/await` with Node.js v6.10.

Look [here](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) to know exactly which versions are supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can bundle your lambda with webpack and babel to write node 8 code and deploy node 6 compatible code.

The easiest way to do this is to use the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) with plugins like :

- [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack)
- [serverless-es7](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-es7)

Answer (score 3):

Node.js v8.10 runtime is available in AWS Lambda as of April 2nd, 2018. Follow the link below for more information:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 2):

You can also write your handler in Typescript which can compile your code to ES5.

You can use `async/await` with Typescript.